# AngularJS directives erroring out - Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Newbie to AngularJS and trying to create a simple directive. The code fails with a 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**JS**

```
var xx = angular.module('myApp', []);
xx.directive('myFoo', 
             function(){
                 return 
                 {
                     template:'23'
                 };                     
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div my-foo></div>
</div>
```

You can find the code and error here https://jsfiddle.net/p11qqrxx/15/

Comment: AngularJS 1.0.0, really?

Comment: New to AngularJS. Is this syntax angularjs 1.0? I am using AngularJS 1.2

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's just your return statement.

Bad:

```
return 
{} // This returns undefined, return is odd and doesn't look at the next line
```

Good:

```
return{
} // Returns an empty object, always open your object on the same line as the return
```

Better:

```
var directive = {};
return directive; // How I always do it, to avoid the issue.
```

Comment: could you please explain with fiddle?

Comment: This explains the basics of what i'm saying: https://jsfiddle.net/L6kmcbnL/ . The issue here has nothing to do with angular, really, just how javascript works. `.directive` expects an argument of a function that returns a configuration object for a directive. The original question's function  returns `undefined` rather than the config object.

Comment: reproduce it with directive..I'll appreciate it

Comment: This is the best I can do without wasting a massive amount of time: https://jsfiddle.net/h3oyzktj/ . It doesn't demo it great, the whole return thing is a syntax error, which breaks the JS, so its not possible to demo both working and not at the same time. If you put the brace on line 8 beside the return on line 7, everything works. The best I can do for now. Ignore the settimeout manual boostrapping of two apps, I was trying to get them to both work and be broken at the same time.

Comment: It was the return...Can't believe that I spent close to 3 hours on this. Once I fixed the return statement it started working.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a issue of Angular but its the way javascript return syntaxes are written and  executed. I have created a simple video which demonstrates this issue in more detail. You can see this video from this link.

https://www.facebook.com/shivprasad.koirala/videos/910570055693818/

Now for the long answer. In javascript "return" and "return ;" are one the same and "{}" is a anonymous function.

When you write return and "{" in the next line its two statements one return and the "{}" is a anonymous function.Program returns from the "return" syntax and the code inside the curly bracket is never executed or we can say its a unreachable code.So it returns back "undefined".

```
return  // returns from this step itself
{
  // any code here will never execute
 // unreachable code
}
```

When you write the curly bracket just after return statment it treats them as one block of code and also executes the code inside the curly bracket.

```
return{
// any code here will execute
}
```

So its all about where your curly bracket is after the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You also referred AngularJs 1.0.0 which was too old, I updated it to 1.1

Change directive to this

```
xx.directive('myFoo',

function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //defaults its A no need of it to declare.
        template: '23'
    };
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p11qqrxx/16/)

Answer (score 0):

xx.directive('myFoo',

function () {
    var obje={
        restrict: 'A', //defaults its A no need of it to declare.
        template: '23'
return obje; 
    }
});